# How to keep running the program on GCE even after the SSH gets disconnected?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I have a long-running program on GCE VM Instance which is connected via SSH with my local PC. But sometimes the SSH gets disconnected and my program stops, and I need to re-run the instance and program. The reason might be due to slow internet connection or integrity monitoring problems.
What I found, On Linux, `nohup` can be used to keep the program running even when the SSH gets disconnected.
My question is how can I do the same for my Google Cloud Instance so that it doesn't depend on my SSH or internet connection. No matter what my program located on VM instance will keep running.

Comment: Convert your program into a Linux service that automatically restarts. There are many articles on this simple process. Here is one: https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6

Answer (score 1):

John Hanley: "Convert your program into a Linux service that automatically restarts. There are many articles on this simple process. Here is one: [https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6"](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6%22)

Answer (score 0):

If it's too much work to convert the program to a service and you just want to make sure it survives disconnects I recommend using [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen). After reconnecting you can always get back to where you left off in your previous session.